# How to force CPU usage of CuPy?

Tags: python, gpu, cpu, cupy

This is a bit of a weird question, as CuPy is meant for GPU. However, depending on the input of my program, I actually want to use the CPU as it is faster. I have already tried

```
if DISABLE_GPU:
  import os
  os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
```

although it blocks access to the GPU, this causes CuPy to throw an error:

```
cupy_backends.cuda.api.runtime.CUDARuntimeError: cudaErrorNoDevice: no CUDA-capable device is detected
```

is there any way to force CuPy to use the CPU instead of the GPU? Or should I use some trick where I say that `cp=np` for instance...

Comment: possibly: https://towardsdatascience.com/heres-how-to-use-cupy-to-make-numpy-700x-faster-4b920dda1f56

Answer (score 1):

CuPy's API is such that any time you use `cp`, you're implicitly working with device memory. So your best bet is to write your code so that it conditionally uses `np` instead of `cp` if you want it to run on the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing agnostic code.

For example:

```
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np
from cupyx.profiler import benchmark

def softplus(x):
    xp = cp.get_array_module(x)
    return xp.sum(x)

x = np.random.random(int(1e5))
x_gpu = cp.asarray(x)

cpu_bench = benchmark(softplus, (x,), n_repeat=10)
gpu_bench = benchmark(softplus, (x_gpu,), n_repeat=10)

print(cpu_bench)
print(gpu_bench)
```

This snippet will use numpy when you pass `x` array, cupy when you pass `x_gpu`.

Comment: I was trying to edit but SO is stuck: sorry for the function name, it was a `softmax` example which I simplified with a reduction sum. Yet the example works as is :D